# Get man page out of preformatted cat page

Tags: documentation

Is there a way to get the source out of the a preformatted man page? I need to parse the man page sources on different platforms and on one pc there are only cat pages, and I don't want to write 2 scripts for both situations.

Greets, Oliver

Answer (score 1):

You can't "generate" the *roff source from a formatted man page.  However, you *could* simply write your script to work with the formatted version, and then run unformatted man pages through nroff.  This way, you write one script instead of two and it works on all your target platforms.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a good solution... then I even don't have to deal with different source formats... thx!

Comment: Hm, now I have the problem that the cat page is VERY difficult to parse due to escape sequences... should I strip them first?

Comment: Probably, yes.  Take a look at the "colcrt" command.  Try, for example, "man ls | colcrt - | less".  In fact, compare "man ls | less -RU" to "man ls | colcrt - | less -RU" to see exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at `man man`.

You can find the source file for a given man page with `man --path command` - so `man --path man` will give a result of `/usr/share/man/en/man1/man.1.gz`